# all builtin function of empty list

Tags: python

Can anybody explain why in python builtin buinction `all` return `True` in this case `all([])`?

```
In [33]: all([])
Out[33]: True

In [34]: all([0])
Out[34]: False

In [35]: __builtins__.all([])
Out[35]: True
```

Comment: `all(l)` is equivalent to `l[0] and l[1] and ...` and the `and` of no things is true.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_domain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not convinced that any of the other answers have really address the question of *why* this should be the case.

The definition for Python's `all()` comes from boolean logic. If for example we say that "all swans are white" then a single black swan disproves the statement. However, if we say that "all unicorns are pink" logicians would take that as a true statement simply because there are no non-pink unicorns. Or in other words "all " is [vacuously true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Practically it gives us a useful invariant. If `all(A)` and `all(B)` are both true then the combination of `all(A + B)` is also true. If `all({})` was false we should have a less useful situation because combining two expressions one of which is false suddenly gives an unexpected true result.

So Python takes `all([]) == True` from boolean logic, and for consistency with other languages with a similar construct.

Taking that back into Python, in many cases the vacuous truth makes algorithms simpler. For example, if we have a tree and want to validate all of the nodes we might say a node is valid if it meets some conditions and all of its children are valid. With the alternative definition  of `all()` this becomes more complex as we have to say it is valid if it meets the conditions and either has no children or all its children are valid.

```
class Node:
    def isValid(self):
        return some_condition(self) and all(child.isValid for child in self.children)
```

Comment: Good explanation. I'd add a few words about `any` and why "some unicorns are pink" is false.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

So, roughly, it's simply defined this way.

You can get around that by using

```
list = []
if list and all(list):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

[As the docs say](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), `all` is equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

For an empty `iterable` the loop body is never executed, so `True` is immediately returned.

Answer (score 0):

Another explanation for this is that `all` and `any` are generalisations of the binary operators `and` and `or` for arbitrarily long numbers of parameters. Thus, `all` and `any` can be defined as:

```
def all(xs):
  return reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, xs, True)

def any(xs):
  return reduce(lambda x,y: x or y, xs, False)
```

The `True` and `False` parameters show that `all([]) == True` and `any([]) == False`.

Answer (score 0):

Any expression with `all` can be rewritten by `any` and vice versa:

```
not all(iterable)
# is the same as:
any(not x for x in iterable)
```

and symmetrically

```
not any(iterable)
# is the same as:
all(not x for x in iterable)
```

These rules require that `all([]) == True`.

---

The function `all` is very useful for readable asserts:

```
assert all(required_condition(x) for x in some_results_being_verified)
```

(It is not so bad if a task has no results, but something is very broken if any result is incorrect.)